# Adding .svn file to all files

Tags: svn, ubuntu-14.04

I removed `.svn` files from all directories in order to reduce file size. Now i want to add `.svn` file in all directories. Is it possible to add again `.svn` file to all directories as what these were previous.

**EDIT**

Actually i wanted to copy my whole code to pen drive. Size was 12 GB. It was copied in speed of bits range. For time consumption i removed all `.svn` files.After removing `.svn` from all directories ,i got size as 7 GB. Unfortunately i forot to take backup. After removing all `.svn` files, i came to know that i dont have any back for this. Now i want to add `.svn` file for all directories.Because if i do fresh checkout it will take more and more time. That is why i asked Is there any possibilities to add `.svn` files again. I also have most aware about `svn`.By my mistake it was happened. If i get any solution for this, it will be easy. So only i asked this question.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. teh .svn-directory contains metadata for Subversion. If you remove the .svn-directory, it ceases working as SVN-Workspace, but any other function the files will have is still there. But you can't simply add the .svn-directories to get it back to a working svn-workspace, the content of these directories is needed too for that. But I don't know for whatever you do, if you really need that. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Deleting the .svn files broke your repository link to those files. You'll probably have to check out a new working copy into another folder, copy the files from your existing folder to that new folder, and check them in again. For future reference: ***Stop deleting files if you don't know what they are!!!***

Comment: @Mnementh See my edit in question.

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR: Yes, I upvoted teh answer of David W., who explains it in detail. I have nothing to add, it covers all. For your small Pen-Drive you might want to use svn export, as that don't create the .svn-directory. But it isn't a working copy of your repository. For your working-copy you should checkout. It takes time, but only once, after that the svn update works on that working copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.svn` is a ***directory***. In Subversion clients 1.6 and lower, they appeared in each directory under Subversion's control. In Subversion 1.7 and higher, it is only in the root of the working directory.

The `.svn` directory does take up space. In the pre-1.6, it actually contained a duplicate entry of each file you checked out -- more than doubling the size of the working directory. However, removing it breaks your working directory. Subversion no longer knows where you did your checkout from, the state of the checkout, or any other information. If you don't need the `.svn` files (for example, you're doing a deployment), you can use `svn export` which downloads all the files, but leaves out the `.svn` directories.

You don't explain why you removed and now want to add these directories back in. You can't simply regenerate them. You'll have to do a new checkout of your project, use some sort of diff between the old working directory and the new one to figure out the changes, and copy those changes back into your working directory. In Ubuntu, you can use `diff -r --brief` to find which files differ (ignoring all the `.svn` warnings about being only in one directory). If you're really good, you can use `diff` to create a patch to apply to the new working directory.

If you are exporting the repository, use `svn export`. If you are doing development, use `svn checkout` and don't touch those `.svn` directories.

Room shouldn't be an issue any more when computers now come with 1/2 a terabyte of disk space by default. You can limit your checkout by only checking out the project you need or by using a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

I also recommend you use SVN 1.7 or better which should work with any Subversion server out there. Earlier versions are no longer supported.